# quartic easing in the distance domain instead of time?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, time, distance

I don't have a known "velocity", i have a number of pixels to traverse, I feed that distance into "moveto" and the graphics on the screen jump to that, or if I feed much smaller values, I get nice smooth objects sliding on screen. Currently I decrement my increment value by 0.1 till it nears zero to produce an "inertial" effect, but this does not land me at the points I wish to land. I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727084/springboard-like-smooth-snap-back-for-onscreen-objects) on stack overflow about handling overshoots, but I found this:

[///////////// QUARTIC EASING: t^4 /////////////////////](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing)

```
// quartic easing in - accelerating from zero velocity 
// t: current time, b: beginning value, c: change in value, d: duration
// t and d can be frames or seconds/milliseconds
Math.easeInQuart = function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
};
```

I want to switch this around so that I get the same effect of landing on a predefined point, but by inputing the current location and the destination location.

I know in Fourier analysis, time domain can be converted to frequency domain. How do I convert time domain to distance domain?

Further, is there a simple transformation I can do with any time based equation or algorithm convert it to a distance based algorithm?

What I'm trying to do is land an object at an exact position or very close with an "intertial" slowdown effect. The quartic easing demo linked above is the one that had the effect I want.

Comment: Do you want to give starting position, ending position, and current position, to determine where to move next frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve the equation.

It seems that the position after time t is `c * (t/d)^4 + b`. If you want this to be a given point p, then `t = d*((p - b)/c)^(1/4)`.

Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I was hoping to leave time out of the equation, so that the speed reduction would be proportional to the distance from the destination: x=getnextposition(currentpos,destinationpos)

Comment: but you can't do that - speed is a function of time. If your function getnextposition doesn't depend on time then nothing prevents you from say staying at currentpos forever and never reaching the destination.

Comment: There is no time other than iterations through the loop that will call the function, and those iterations can vary in time depending on system load...

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as answered, even though I don't exactly understand your answer as it pertains to a time based system as opposed to an iterations / distance based system, the two may be the same, I don't know.